# how to solve $|z|^2 + z|z| + 2 = 2i Im(z)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

this is the process I follow:

- $z|z|  = 2iImz -|z|^2- 2 $
- $z \sqrt{Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2} = 2iy - (Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2) - 2$
- $z\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} =2iy -(x^2+y^2)-2$
- $z=(2iy -(x^2+y^2)-2)/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

then i get: $Im(z)=2y/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $Re(z)=(-(x^2+y^2)-2)/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

what should i do next?

Comment: Spoiler: [There *aren't* any solutions.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=abs%28z%29%5E2%2Bz*abs%28z%29%2B2%3D2i*Im%28z%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by looking at the real and imaginary parts separately, inspired by the fact that the LHS has a lot of things that are purely real while the RHS is purely imaginary. So focusing on the imaginary part gives us:

$$\begin{eqnarray}Im(|z|^2 + z|z| + 2) & = & Im(2i Im(z)) \\
Im(z)|z| & = & 2 Im(z) \\
\implies |z| = 2 & \lor & Im(z) = 0\end{eqnarray}$$

If we check the $Im(z) = 0$ case first, that means $z \in \mathbb{R}$, and the equation becomes:

$2z^2 + 2 = 0 \implies z^2 = -1$

which has no solutions over the reals.

So the only possibly solutions are where $|z| = 2$, and if we put that into the equation we get:

$$\begin{eqnarray}2^2 + 2z + 2 & = & 2i Im(z) \\
z + 3 & = & 2i Im(z) \\
Re(z + 3) & = & Re(2i Im(z)) \\
Re(z) + 3 & = & 0 \implies Re(z) = -3 \end{eqnarray}$$

but this is a problem, because $|z|^2 \geq Re(z)^2$ which would mean $2^2 \geq (-3)^2$ which is clearly a contradiction.

So in fact there are no solutions to this equation.

Answer (score 2):

You may simplify the notation from the beginning. Call $z=a+bi$ and your equation becomes:

$$a^2+b^2+(a+bi)\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+2=2bi$$ or

$$[a^2+b^2+a\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+2]+[bi\sqrt{a^2+b^2}]=2bi$$

So, you can split it into the real part and the imaginary part.

$$a^2+b^2+a\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+2=0\quad (1)$$

$$b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2b \quad (2).$$

From $(2)$ you get $b=0$ or $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2$.

Can you finish?

Comment: understood, I always deleted the b making the root = 2 but I got values outside the set of the real numbers which made me think I made a mistake.

Comment: i will try with  b =0

Comment: i get a=-3 and b=sqrt(-5)

Comment: b=0 then a=sqrt(-1)

Comment: @FranciscoEstrella, So, you found that the problem has no solution because $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Congrats, you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Write $z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$ with $r,\theta\in\Bbb{R}$; your equation becomes $r^2+r\times r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+2=2ir\sin\theta$.
Identifying real and imaginary parts of the left & right members, you get:
$\begin{cases}
r^2(1+\cos\theta)+2=0&(1)\\[5pt]
r^2\sin\theta=2r\sin\theta&(2)
\end{cases}$

Now (1) implies that there is no solution to the problem… (Or did I make a mistake?)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion (no solution exists) so I’d say you’re correct.